# How to copy a Django Polymorphic object?

Tags: django, django-polymorphic

Using the `django-polymorpic` module has been a great way of simplifying object inheritance where a number of subclasses all inherit from, and share several attributes with, a base class.  But while almost everything works pretty much like a normal object, the method of wiping out the `.pk` and calling `save()` doesn't work?  I've tried:

```
o = MyPolymorphicSubTable.objects.first()
print(o.pk) # 22
o.pk = None
o.save()
print(o.pk) # still 22 -- still the same object
```

And also tried:

```
print(o.id) # 22
o.id = None
o.save()
print(o.id) # still 22
```

anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a hint toward an answer in an old issue on the polymorphic github issues, and finally found an answer.  The id (22) of the object is stored as `.id` (the base table id) and also as .basetablename_ptr (in my case, 'sectioninfo_ptr')-- the latter is not settable but the `.pk` references the same field, and *is* settable, so both the two approaches need to be combined:

```
o = MyPolymorphicSubTable.objects.first()
print(o.pk) # 22
o.pk = None
o.id = None # both this and the previous line need to be there
o.save()
print(o.pk) # 434
print(o.id) # 434
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512349/4391298) unfortunately only works with a single level of inheritance. If you have another level of inheritance you'll run into [this bug (#414)](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/issues/414).

As a workaround, you can unset the various `_ptr` fields running up the inheritance tree. Assuming `ModelA`, `ModelB` and `ModelC`, then `ModelC` will have a `modela_ptr` and a `modelb_ptr`. This code will search the field list for those pointers and unset them:

```py
self.pk = self.id = None

# However if we have three levels of inheritance, we also need
# to clear the pointers, else we'll end up with an UPDATE rather
# than an INSERT still.
for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=True):
    if not isinstance(field, models.OneToOneField):
        continue

    # Test this is a pointer to something in our own inheritance
    # tree
    if not isinstance(self, field.related_model):
        continue

    setattr(self, field.attname, None)
```

Comment: Thank you! An important case that I didn't test since we've limited polymorphic inheritance to one level.